# VLC aren't open on my TV

Tags: debian, vlc, hdmi

The VLC works perfectly on the monitor of my notebook, but when I output the screen to my LCD TV through a HDMI cable, it don't open. Months ago things are working right. Now I can only open VLC through cvlc command.

I have googled this a lot. Have tried all that solutions to delete the VLC config file, purge and reinstall the package, install new libs, modify some file of VLC to not use QT and others things in this sense.

Here [are the log](https://pastebin.com/hbRTPLVr) from when I try to start VLC throught the terminal. And now the [cvlc output](https://pastebin.com/dSeZ6esK).

I'm using Debian 9 with XFCE.

Here are some informations [about the hardware.](https://pastebin.com/nwb1CQAR)

Comment: Intel bug? You have an Intel video card, dont you? The questions could be better, namely naming your hardware and models.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Done. It's enough?